# Tweeting from android using a twitter dialog

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter4j

I am using [Twitter4j Library](http://twitter4j.org) on my android application. Is there any way to tweet using a tweeter dialog that user can edit the tweet text? I don't want to tweet programmatically, Something like a [facebook dialogs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/dialogs).

Comment: You're probably looking for web intents https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents

Comment: @PopoFibo yes, something like that. Can you direct me a guide / link for this on android?

Answer (score 0):

```
This is URL to tweet directly to twitter

   http://twitter.com/share?text=" + shareDescription + "&url=http://" + shareURL


   Add below code where you want to call tweet action
`enter code here`
     ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

            TwitterShare d = new TwitterShare(getActivity(), progressDialog,
                    "http://twitter.com/share?text=" + shareDescription
                            + "&url=http://" + shareURL);
            d.show();

            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            progressDialog.show();

create one class add below code to that class.This class opens the webview and it redirect to particular URL

    enter code here
public class TwitterShare extends Dialog {
    ProgressDialog progress;
    String shareURL;

    ImageView close;

    public TwitterShare(Context context, ProgressDialog progress,
            String shareURL) {
        super(context);
        this.progress = progress;
        this.shareURL = shareURL;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);// must call before super.
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.ln_dialog);

        close = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.close_button);

        WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webkitWebView1);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mWebView.loadUrl(shareURL);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

        mWebView.setPictureListener(new PictureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNewPicture(WebView view, Picture picture) {
                if (progress != null && progress.isShowing()) {
                    progress.dismiss();
                }

            }
        });

        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                TwitterShare.this.cancel();

            }
        });

    }

    class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            Log.i("url", url);

            view.loadUrl(url);

            return true;
        }
    }
}

Layout file for Webview

    enter code here
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-``8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="300dip"
    android:layout_height="480dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webkitWebView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/close_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`enter code here`
        android:src="@drawable/close_button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this might work but how can i add a listener that after tweeting it will close the webview rather than continuing it to the twitter site?

Comment: use close button to close the webview. no way to add listener without SDK